# How to match datasets in R based on two non-unique variables?

Tags: r, merge, match

I have two dataframes, one of failed firms, and one of non-failed firms.

They both comprise of rows of observations of firms, the variables in these rows include the industry of firm, the year where financial information was recorded, and the size of total assets of the firm and others.

I want to match each failed firm with one non-failed firm of the same industry and total asset size and year of financial information recorded.

I am happy to throw away observations with no match. If one failed firm matches multiple nonfailed firms, I am happy to just randomly choose one.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
merge(cessdurc1[cessdurc1$afcyear=="2007",], cessdura[cessdura$afcyear=="2007",], by=c("ssic", "total_assets"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

Which does not work because the columns chosen need to be unique.

My data looks like this:

```
>head(alivefirms)
  failed within year total_assets afcyear ssic
1              0        9e+07    2007   20
2              0        7e+06    2007   43
3              0        7e+05    2007   46
4              0        1e+07    2007   82
5              0        1e+08    2007   93
6              0        1e+06    2007   11

> head(failedfirms)
    failed within year total_assets afcyear ssic
26                1        20000    2007   41
79                1         5000    2007   73
105               1          400    2007   30
127               1         4000    2007   18
133               1         2000    2007   70
154               1        10000    2007   41
```

I want the output to match failed firms to alive firms who have the same SSIC & Total Assets & Afcyear, so something that looks like this

```
> head(wantedoutput)
    failed within year total_assets afcyear ssic
26                1       20000     2007   41
79                0       20000     2007   41
105               1         400     2007   30
127               0         400     2007   30
133               1        2000     2007   70
154               0        2000     2007   70
```

Comment: merging and matching are very different operations.  In the end, I suspect you will want to stack your data frames on top of each other and then use a package such as `Matching`, `MatchIt`, or `optmatch` to get your matched data set.  This will come with numerous benefits over randomly matching firms from one data set to the other (such as matching within industry and asset size, for example).

Comment: You should add some example data and the expected output.

Comment: @Molx Hi thanks for your suggestion, I have added the example data and expected output